# How to set vsftpd to put one directory on the server

Tags: server, vsftpd

I have an external HDD that i keep all my stuff on but when i wanted something of the drive or i had stuff to put on it i had to go get it plug it in do what i need to do, unplug it and then put it back. So i wanted to setup a local home ftp server so that i could just access from filezilla or somthing from anywhere in my house.

So, i got the latest version of `vsftpd`(via `apt-get`) and went through the `vsftpd.conf` file but i didn’t find option to point it to the location that i wanted it to put as the server(in this case i wanted to point it to the `/media` directory where my drive is located). This is where i need the help.

I have seen on the internet that apparently there was an earlier version that had an option in the config file to point it to a home directory which i'm assuming could be used to point to where i wanted, but i looked over this config file several times to make sure, but its not there.

Comment: Could you please pout your `vsftpd.conf` file?  The standard is that if you connect by name, it goes to your `home` directory and if you connect anonymously, there is no default but the example conf file has an option to put it on `/srv/ftp`...  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default login directory for `vsftpd`, change the ftp user home directory in `/etc/passwd`:

```
ftp:x:116:116:vsftpd daemon:/media:/bin/false
```